# how to set the current location when there is no address entered using google map

Tags: angular, google-maps

i am using google map api, and when there is no address entered and click on a button, it must show the current location of a user. 
I had tried in many ways, but here i get a error as naative element is undefined. I am not able to fix this issue.

TS:

```
getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
  }
  showPosition(position) {

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
  }

  initMap() {
    this.mapShow = true;
    this.getLocation()
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="w-100 h-100 border border-primary" #gmap [hidden]="!mapShow"></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="initMap()"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> View on Map</a>
```

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yp9cxx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue and it appears "this" was null in the showPosition call back. Instead of a separate function I used the fat arrow syntax which allows for a valid this reference. Here is the code I used to get it to work.

```
    getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
```

Also if you are not able to use the fat arrow syntax you can assign your "this" to a global variable and then use that in the callback.